# sql - Postgresql, increment column based on other column values

Tags: postgresql

I have table like

```
create table test(employee integer NOT NULL, code character varying(200), number integer)
```

I want to auto increment column 'number' on every insert record

```
insert into test(employee, code) values(17,'bangalore')
insert into test(employee, code) values(17,'bangalore')
insert into test(employee, code) values(17,'mumbai')
```

I want result like

```
employee    code        number
17          bangalore   1
17          bangalore   2
17          bangalore   3
17          mumbai      1
17          mumbai      2
17          bangalore   4
17          mumbai      3
18          bangalore   1
18          bangalore   2
18          mumbai      1
18          mumbai      2
```

Comment: Do **not** post code or additional information in comments. **[edit]** your question.

Comment: Why do you want to store that information? You can easily generate those numbers while retrieving the data.

Comment: i want to store as the same data is referenced at multiple places

Comment: Your table has no primary key yet. And, with your design, it naturally would be the whole table. Why not just add a single `serial` to have a smaller primary key? It would make the ordering clear too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table test (employee integer NOT NULL, code character varying(200), number integer)

    insert into test(employee, code, number ) values(17,'bangalore',(select coalesce(max(number) + 1,1)  from test where employee = 17 and code = 'bangalore'));
    insert into test(employee, code, number ) values(17,'bangalore',(select coalesce(max(number) + 1,1)  from test where employee = 17 and code = 'bangalore'));
    insert into test(employee, code, number ) values(17,'mumbai',(select coalesce(max(number) + 1,1)  from test where employee = 17 and code = 'mumbai'));
```

Comment: I would use `max` rather than `count`. What if some rows are deleted?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Yes you are right. and we have to change count(*) + 1 to coalesce(max(number) + 1,1).

Comment: This works fine for single insert, but i wanted for batch update.

Comment: This works fine for batch update but the same time if i do batch update second time then the problem comes.

Comment: what is problem can you please explain.

Answer (score 1):

For a batch upload of data, try if below approach would be useful.

create a temporary table test2

```
create table test2(employee integer NOT NULL, code character varying(200))

insert into test2(employee, code) values(17,'bangalore')
insert into test2(employee, code) values(17,'bangalore')
insert into test2(employee, code) values(17,'mumbai')
```

Insert into actual table along with incremental number

```
insert into test(employee, code, number) 
select employee, code, row_number() over (partition by code )  from test2
```

You could include *order by* clause like primary key column or another column like created_date  :

```
over (partition by code order by created_date)
```